# JS - how to remove setTimeOut for my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, cleartimeout

I am trying to use vertical scroll to display an object ***A***.
The idea is that if my scroll height is greater than ***scrollHeight (15)***, then after ***1.2 second***, ***A*** will show up. 
Then when I scroll back to top, A will hide.

The problem right now is that if I dont use clearTimeout, the **setTimeout** will ignore the condition: ***if ( scroll >= scrollHeight )***

When I use **clearTimeout**, it seems it only works when I scroll very quickly or it just doesnt work.

Here is my code.

```
var scrollHeight = 15;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
    var delayThis;

    if ( scroll >= scrollHeight ) {
        delayThis = setTimeout(function(){

        //Display **A**... 

        }, 1200);

       }
       else{
        // Hide **A** ...
        clearTimeout(delayThis);
        }
  }
```

Thank you very much for helping!!

Comment: The scroll event fires almost continously, and you keep adding timeouts but the reference to those timeouts are lost, mostly because the variable is defined inside the scroll function, and the if else makes no sense, either you create timeout, or you clear a variable that isn't defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the script if the message is already showing or not, that way you avoid the multiple delays. Below is a working version of what I'm talking about. I hope that helps.

```js
var scrollHeight = 15;
var message = $( ".message" ); 
var messagestatus = false;
var scrollposition;

$(window).scroll(function() { 
    scrollposition = $(document).scrollTop();
    
    if ( scrollposition >= scrollHeight ) {
        if ( messagestatus == false ) {
            setTimeout(function(){

                message.show();
                messagestatus = true;
                
            }, 1200);
        }

    } else{
        message.hide();
        messagestatus = false;
    } 
});
```

```css
.message {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>top</p>
<div class="message">
    Show!
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<p>bottom</p>
```

Comment: to continue my comment, the flag makes my code (which includes clearTimeout work), however, your code doesn't remove setTimeOut as this is what i asked in this question.  Thank you again for your answer that makes my code work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put delayThis outside of the event, up with scrollHeight. Because otherwise it no longer exists. Right now you have it where it is only local to that one scroll event... not the proceeding ones.

Also... you would be setting the timeout over and over as you scroll. So before setting it you probably want to be make sure that delayThis is not already set.

Comment: Thank you for point out delayThis's position! But Ricardo's answer solves the problem